Derivation in Gap Statistic
I am reading the paper "Estimating the number of clusters in data set via the gap statistic" by Tibshirani (2001), and there is a formula that I do not see how it is derived. It says
$$
E[\log(W_k)] = \log(pn/12) - (2/p)\log(k) + C 
$$
To give some context, $W_k$ is the error measure for the algorithm and is defined to be
$$
W_k = \sum^{k}_{r = 1} \frac{1}{2n_r} D_r, 
$$
where $D_r$ is the sum of pairwise distances for all observations in the cluster $r$ and is defined as
$$
D_r = \sum_{i,i' \in C_r}d_{ii'} . 
$$
I do not see how this is derived. Can anyone explain this to me? This is on page 413 of the paper. I have attached the link to the paper below. Thanks!

Link for the paper: https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/63/2/411/7083348

Hi, Matthew. I think it'd help if you also show what $W$ is. Your chances of being answered will also increase if you show the work of some of your own attempts at deriving this result.
